# Is it possible to generate Type with modified typed keys?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to create Typescript Type based on object that modifies its keys?

For example this is the thing I would like to achieve:

```
const super: SuperType<{getData: any}> = ...
super.getDataEXTENSION (Note it should have this modified key)
```

I know we can define

```
type ModifiedName<T extends string> = `${Capitalize<T>}EXTENSION`;
type GetObjectWithModifiedPropertyNames<T extends any> = {
  [key in keyof T]: any;
};
```

but calculating the keys is problematic:

```
type GetObjectWithModifiedPropertyNames<T extends any> = {
  [key: ModifiedName<keyof T>]: any;
};
```

I know it is possible to modify return type, arguments etc but regarding modifying the keys I am not sure it is possible.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/Nrv01N) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared/unimported types or values.  `super` is a reserved word.  And when you say something is "problematic" it is helpful to include a description of the problem, along with specific errors.

Comment: Looks like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/N9JL3m) is what you want, but there are some typos or something you should probably clear up (you `Capitalize` the key but you want `getDataEXTENSION` instead of `GetDataEXTENSION`?  Not sure which part is the mistake).  If you fix the question I'm happy to write up an answer.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`as` syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) in a mapped type:

```
type ModifiedName<T extends string> = `${Capitalize<T>}EXTENSION`

type Foo = {foo: string, bar: number}

// type ModifiedFoo = {FooEXTENSION: string, BarEXTENSION: number}
type ModifiedFoo = {[K in keyof Foo as ModifiedName<K>]: Foo[K]}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwJYDMkQQOQIYFsIA8AKlBAB7AQB2CAzlLcAE5JUDmAfFALxQAGAEgDeAYWxgkwbABskAL0JEOAXwCiADSKrMAZQCSAeUx8AUCdCQoAMThweUISlsAuBs1ZsANFABG2Jq5UAK64PhBMymYA9FFQFtDwyGgYNna8QqkaWrqGmK6MLOzeAEL+Wdr6RoEhYRHm4AmIqOgIqfZCANoA0lCsUADWECBwKNa2UNj0ic0YOPgEXRwAuq6p3UuRQA)

Answer (score 2):

You can use TypeScript's conditional type syntax to only allow keys that are type of string.  The following will define *ModifiedName* as the Capitalized key + EXTENSION only if key it extends string.  Otherwise the key will not be used in the type since the false response of the condition is *never*.

```
type ModifiedName<T extends string | number | Symbol> =
  `${ T extends string ? Capitalize<T> : never }EXTENSION`;

type GetObjectWithModifiedPropertyNames<T> = {
  [key in ModifiedName<keyof T>]: any;
};
```

Here's an example of shows a valid usage scenario.  It will not expect 1EXTENSION to be a key, and adding a property of `['1EXTENSION']` would result in an error.

```
interface Foo {
    abc: number;
    efg: string;
    1: string;
}
let obj: GetObjectWithModifiedPropertyNames<Foo> = {
    AbcEXTENSION: 'hi',
    EfgEXTENSION: 'avc'
};
```